# sFtp with key authentication prompts password

Tags: sftp, private-key, ppk

A newbie about sFtp and and authentication via key files.
Here is my problem;

1- I have an .p12 certificate(provided by the host owner); which I used openssl to extract my private key(.pem) file out of it.

2-Using this file; I tried to login via WinSCP client; and since WinSCP does not support .pem files; I converted the file into .ppk format.

3-When I try to login with my .ppk file; seems like host does not refuse my key file; but still prompts be a password(which I dont have, because authentication is via key files only). So I am not sure where did I do wrong and why server still prompts me a password;so I am stuck with a "Further authentication required" message.

Here are my WinSCP client logs when I try to login :

```
. Looking up host "xxxxx.yyyy" for SSH connection
. Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
. We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.11
. Server version: SSH-2.0-SSHD
. Using SSH protocol version 2
. Have a known host key of type rsa2
. Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. Host key fingerprint is:
. ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
. Verifying host key rsa2 0x....
. Host key matches cached key
. Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
. Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
. Reading key file "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\private.ppk"
! Using username "myusername".
. Server offered these authentication methods: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
. Offered public key
. Offer of public key accepted
! Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
. Sent public key signature
! Further authentication required
```

Comment: Is the .p12 really a certificate? Or just a simple private key? - Can you login with PuTTY? Or any other SSH/SFTP client? - How did you convert the .pem to .ppk? Also you mention first .p12 and them .pem, those are different formats - Did you get any information with that .p12 file from the host owner?

Comment: .p12 is really a certificate. I cant login with putty or any other ftp client(CoreFTP,Filezilla etc..).I used openssl to get. pem file from certificate and  I used Putty Gen for coverting .pem file into .ppk. My host owner mentioned something getting "passphrase"; I also created my keys using passphrase as well; but this time WinSCP asks passphrase; and then asks password again. I am just trying to be sure that, the issue is client or server related.

Comment: Did the owner include more information?

Answer (score 0):

Standard SSH/SFTP protocol does not use certificates. Only a simple key pair.

There's a proprietary implementation in OpenSSH that allows it using certificates:
https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.certkeys?annotate=HEAD

But that's implemented by OpenSSH toolset only (both client and server).

WinSCP, FileZilla or PuTTY (and others) do not support this proprietary authentication method.

*But your server does not seem to be OpenSSH. So the information that you have a certificate can actually be wrong.*

Comment: actually , I am just using certificate(.p12) to extract my private/public key; as you see in the logs; I am sending my public key to server(which I believe it is a valid key; because I also tried to modify key and saw an "key is rejected" message from the server)